# How to step by step build the circuit in TOR

Tags: python, networkx, tor, tcpdump, stem

I have this piece of code which is a simple code to create and/or extend a circuit in TOR using stem.

```
import getpass
import sys
import argparse
import stem
import stem.connection
from stem.control import Controller

if __name__ == '__main__':
  try:
    controller = Controller.from_port()
  except stem.SocketError as exc:
    print("Unable to connect to tor on port 9051: %s" % exc)
    sys.exit(1)

  try:
    controller.authenticate()
  except stem.connection.MissingPassword:
    pw = getpass.getpass("Controller password: ")

    try:
      controller.authenticate(password = pw)
    except stem.connection.PasswordAuthFailed:
      print("Unable to authenticate, password is incorrect")
      sys.exit(1)
  except stem.connection.AuthenticationFailure as exc:
    print("Unable to authenticate: %s" % exc)
    sys.exit(1)
  controller.extend_circuit('0')
  controller.extend_circuit('0')
  print("Tor is running version %s" % controller.get_network_statuses())
  for entry in controller.get_network_statuses():
    print (entry)
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument("-hopno", "--hopno", help="Number of hops btw nodes")
  known_args = parser.parse_known_args()
  #print(known_args)

  controller.close()
```

What I want is to build the circuit step by step (for example in the first step from client to first hop then continue to next hop)

How may I achieve this goal.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, you might have to break this down into a much smaller chunk and ask again to get responses.

Comment: @RamNarasimhan a small chunk would be to build the circle step by step. I mean from client to first hop then if I want to next hop etc...

Comment: Okay great. If you can, you should edit your question to reflect that, and hopefully, you will get some responses.

Comment: @RamNarasimhan done as suggested! grazie